# How can I provision a Vault certificate that is valid longer than its signing CA?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am currently getting the following error when trying to provision a certificate from the Vault PKI backend:

```
cannot satisfy request, as TTL would result in notAfter 2029-08-04T12:05:04.236196294Z that is beyond the expiration of the CA certificate at 2029-08-04T11:56:22Z
```

I noticed in the code that you seem to be able to disable this check in the PKI role with the `AllowExpirationPastCA` field (https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/master/builtin/logical/pki/cert_util.go#L899):

```
        if caSign != nil &&
            notAfter.After(caSign.Certificate.NotAfter) && !data.role.AllowExpirationPastCA {

            return nil, errutil.UserError{Err: fmt.Sprintf(
                "cannot satisfy request, as TTL would result in notAfter %s that is beyond the expiration of the CA certificate at %s", notAfter.Format(time.RFC3339Nano), caSign.Certificate.NotAfter.Format(time.RFC3339Nano))}
        }
```

but the PKI HTTP API for createe/update role doesn't seem to support this field: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/pki/index.html#create-update-role

How can provision a certificate that lasts longer than its signing CA? My usecase is that I want to provision certificates for as long as possible, which also does not seem straightforward without reading the expiration time of the CA first.

`vault --version`: Vault v1.0.3 ('85909e3373aa743c34a6a0ab59131f61fd9e8e43')

EDIT: There is an issue open already https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/5834